# M1 Max MBP external 4k Monitor via DisplayLink Hub looks blurry/fuzzy?

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macbook

I have the MBP M1 Max and a DIsplayLink Hub connected to a 4k BenQ monitor and it looks blurry and the text is not clear.

I've recently switched from Windows and my BenQ monitor was super clear there.

I've been doing some research and it was suggested to use [BetterDisplay](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay) to change the resolution - While it has fixed it a little bit, it isn't perfect.

It seems that my BenQ monitor PPI is 163 and I've been reading that it is because of that low PPI, the scaling on MacOS doesn't work very well? Apprently, I need a monitor with at least 218 PPI to have more clear text?

But why does Windows 11 display text much clearer compared to when using my 4k monitor as an external monitor via my MBP? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I suspect its more the displaylink hub and drivers than the monitor. Can you try plugging in the monitor directly?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, I also have another monitor plugged in via USB Type C to DP and it looks much better. But I got the hub because I have 3 monitors. Why is DisplayLink so bad then, do you know?

Comment: displaylink's basically .... a small, crappy video card that does stuff over USB. It just isn't very good

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I see! So is something like the Apple Studio DIsplay at 218 PPI a better option for heavy text work?

Comment: there's probably better options - thunderbolt or even USB C hubs for example that would let you use your current monitors.